# MicrosoftWordBridge could not be created - Documents4j

Tags: java, documents4j

I have this problem.

```
class com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge could not be created by a (File, long, TimeUnit) constructor
at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.make(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:32)
at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.makeAll(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:42)
at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.loadConfiguration(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:85)
at com.documents4j.conversion.DefaultConversionManager.<init>(DefaultConversionManager.java:22)
at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.makeConversionManager(LocalConverter.java:79)
at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.<init>(LocalConverter.java:51)
at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter$Builder.build(LocalConverter.java:186)
```

Notes:

- MS Office is installed
- The PDF/XPS add-on is installed in MS Office.

My Code:

```
File wordFile = new File(inputFile), target = new File(outputFile);
File temp = new File("D:\\directorio_aplicacion\\todos\\pisac\\docs\\");

IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
                                .baseFolder(temp)
                                .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .build();

Future<Boolean> conversion = converter.convert(wordFile).as(DocumentType.PDF)
                                .to(target).as(DocumentType.DOCX)
                                .schedule();
```

Please. 
How can I solve this error?

[image: Jar in Project]

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and investigated the error? This should normally work.